# Google Search combines my homepage's title with the title from a blog subdirectory?

Tags: google-search, search-results, title

I am creating a personal website with a static HTML page containing some links. The title of the site is: `Andrew Hunt | Web Apps`. On the same site/server I also created a blog under the directory `/blog/` and the title of the blog is: `Andrew's Space | A Web Dev Blog`.

I thought I'd check how the blog was showing up in Google Search and it shows up like this: `Andrew's Space | A Web Dev Blog - Andrew Hunt | Web Apps` So the titles have joined together separated by a hyphen. The main website title is not in the code for the blog.

The main website is `http://example.com/` with a static index.html with title `<title>Andrew Hunt | Web Apps</title>`

The blog is at`http://example.com/blog/` it is a Wordpress blog with the title set as `Andrew's Space` and tagline `A Web Dev Blog` The title tag looks as follows: `<title>Andrew&#039;s Space | A Web Dev Blog</title>`

In google I type `andrews space a web dev blog` as the query.

I would rather the search engine return just the full blog title I.e `Andrew's Space | A Web Dev Blog`

Is there a way I can change this?

Comment: If a title or description is too short - Google will take the one you've set and add content it seems relevant from the page to flesh it out. This content is usually a title or key phrase in the article.

Comment: Did you check your Wordpress *site url*? Maybe it's the reason?